# Key binding in terminal emacs

Tags: key-bindings, terminal-emacs

I started to use Linux Mint. On the `Terminal`, I can use `emacs -nw` and `emacs`. I can't get the same key behavior about the following two configs. In particular, these settings work in `emacs`, but not in `emacs -nw`. How do I fix this issue?

`(global-set-key (kbd "<C-tab>") 'other-window)`

`(define-key ess-mode-map (kbd "C-%") "%>%")`

Comment: What kind of Terminal do you use? Is it configurable?

Answer (score 1):

Terminals can't send `<C-tab>`.

The tab character in a terminal is `TAB` which is the same thing as `C-i`, and you obviously can't send `C-C-i`, so there's no such thing as `C-TAB` from a terminal's perspective.

That's not the only issue, though -- GUI environments have *lots* of key events that terminals don't send, so unless you're using a terminal emulator with special support for such modern things, there will be plenty of keys that you can't use.